# How to map a C# enum to a Cassandra field using Datastax C# Driver?

Tags: c#, enums, cassandra, datastax

I would like to save and retrieve a POCO object to and from Cassandra using the Datastax C# Driver (.Net Framework 4.6.1, Datastax C# Driver 3.0.8)

Example:

```
public enum DocumentState
{
    New = 0,
    Approved = 1,
    Rejected = 2
}

public class DocumentReadModel
{
    public Guid DocumentId { get; set; }
    public DocumentState State { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best way to persist this object in Cassandra?

My approach does not seem to work.

For now I tried to save it as int in Cassandra:

```
create table if not exists documentreadmodel (
        documentid uuid PRIMARY KEY,
        state int);
```

Also used the Mapping Configuration offered by the Datastax driver with the following code:

```
MappingConfiguration.Global.Define(
    new Map<DocumentReadModel>()
            .TableName("documentreadmodel")
            .PartitionKey(o => o.MerchantId)
            .Column(o => o.State, c =>     c.WithName("state").WithDbType<int>()));
```

But I still get an exception:

```
Cassandra.InvalidTypeException: 
Unknown Cassandra target type for CLR type ValueObjects.DocumentState
```

Should the I use another type that int in Cassandra?
Configure the driver differently?

Comment: hm... the mapping is correct, are you using the `Mapper.Insert()` method? Make sure you are defining your mappings before calling the mapper methods. I've just pushed an integration test to the repo covering a similar scenario that you described: https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/pull/268

Comment: Thanks. I was using the driver through my company own wrapper hence the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution by updating the Global config to use For

I am using .NET 4.5.2 CassandraCSharpDriver 3.3.2

Try updating your configuration to use "For"

```
MappingConfiguration.Global.Define(
For<DocumentReadModel>()
        .TableName("documentreadmodel")
        .PartitionKey(o => o.MerchantId)
        .Column(o => o.State, c => c.WithName("state").WithDbType<int>()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a pretty old question but might help others who encounter these issues...

To save an Enum to cassandra you need to define a convertor function to convert from your Enum to Int.
It should be something like this:

```
public class MyTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    protected override Func<TDatabase, TPoco> GetUserDefinedFromDbConverter<TDatabase, TPoco>()
    {
        if (typeof(TDatabase) == typeof(Int32) && typeof(TPoco) == typeof(DocumentState))
        {
            Func<Int32, DocumentState> func = documentState=> (DocumentState)documentState;
            return (Func<TDatabase, TPoco>)(object)func;
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected override Func<TPoco, TDatabase> GetUserDefinedToDbConverter<TPoco, TDatabase>()
    {
        if (typeof(TDatabase) == typeof(Int32) && typeof(TPoco) == typeof(DocumentState))
        {
            Func<Provider, Int32> func = documentState=>
                    ((Int32)documentState);

            return (Func<TPoco, TDatabase>)(object)func;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Then when defining your table you should register the convertor:

```
        var mapping = new MyMapping();
        var table = new Table<T>(session, new MappingConfiguration()
            .ConvertTypesUsing(new MyTypeConverter())
            .Define(mapping));
```

When querying cassandra the driver uses serializers(not the TypeConverter), And they do not support Enums. So you have to replace the Enum with Int. I use LINQ and it looks like that:

```
        int documentStateInt = (int)documentState;
        Expression<Func<DocumentReadModel, bool>> predicate;
        predicate= drm => (int)drm.State == documentStateInt;

        return table.Where(predicate).ExecuteAsync();
```

*Using driver version 3.16